# Jquery scroll fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin. The fadeout effect is working when I scroll down but when I scroll back to the top it's does not show my div again (#header)
What do I need to change in order to make the div appear again?

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
        $('#header').addClass('animated fadeOut');
        console.log('fadeOut');
    } else if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
        $('#header').show();
        console.log('fadein');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here!

Comment: @CodeiSir My question is not showing my element when i scroll

Comment: It's probably because you do not remove the class fadeout, and instead use show. Maybe instead of giving the item you make dissappear the class fadeout, you call .fadeOut() on it, and then make it show again when you want it to. Also you're using the same selector for both the fadeout and show, which smells like an error.

Comment: Humm... maybe my eyes are not working well but, having the same condition on `if` and `else if` statements isn't just useless?

Comment: @frikinside what thing  isn't useless ?

Comment: isn't useless no. IS useless having the same condition on ìf` and `else if`. Maybe is just a typo, but if not you must check it out!

Comment: @frikinside                                                                            `$(window).scroll( function(){
           
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){   
         $('#header:in-viewport').addClass('animated fadeOut')
              //console.log('addfade');
            }
           
           if ($(this).scrollTop() < 720){   
         $('#header:above-the-top').addClass('animated fadeIn')
              //console.log('addfade');
            }
            
  
           });`

Comment: @frikinside i'm using plugin veiwport selectors , it's works when i scroll down but when i scroll up my element it's  hidden why ?

Comment: @achrafbans The code in your comment differs from the one you posted. Maybe would be a good idea to update the question with the right code. It would be better if we know more info about css and markup but in a first guess I would say that adding `fadeIn` class isn't overriding the `fadeOut` class. I think that adding a `.removeClass('fadeOut')` should work

Comment: BTW checking the code provided in the code makes no sense for me. I can't figure out what you want to achieve. Why are you trying to show an element that are outside the current viewport? and hiding when in the viewport zone? I just don't get it, i really want to help but I can't figure out how! Please detail your question and provide the REAL working code. PD: Please add a tag in your question that this is about `Viewport Selectors for jQuery` plugin

Comment: @frikinside check [https://achraf-cv.herokuapp.com] look header when scroll it's fadeout but when i scroll to up in header it's hidden i'm ussing this code                    `  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){   
         $('#header:in-viewport').addClass('animated fadeOut');
              console.log('addfade');
            }
           
           else if(($(this).scrollTop() < 500)){
              $('#header:above-the-top').removeClass('animated fadeOut');
              console.log('remove fade');
           }`

Comment: @frikinside i'm sorry for my english it's not very good

Comment: @achrafbans my english isn't good either :P Well I think that with the last comment I know what you need, let me prepare an answer and see if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't understand why you use the if else if statement with the same condition. 
Anyway I suggest you to give to #header the display: none; with css and after manage the fadeIn and Out with JQuery.
Try to change your code in that way:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
    $('#header').fadeOut(2000); //You can change the fadeOut parameter
    console.log('fadeOut');
} else if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
    $('#header').fadeIn(2000);
    console.log('fadein');
}
});
```

Or if you prefer to show and hide your div without an Animation you can use show and hide methods.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
    $('#header').hide(); //You can change the fadeOut parameter
    console.log('fadeOut');
} else if ($('#header:above-the-top')) {
    $('#header').show();
    console.log('fadein');
}
```

Or at least if you want to use the class you have to remove and add the class in order to animate it.Remember the two methods hasClass() and removeClass().

Comment: the probleme is when i scrol to up it's hidden my header why ?

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to do? Do you want to hide and display the header for example when the scroll is over 100px from top?Sorry it is just to understand

Comment: Sorry but the code pen link is not working. Try to look at this post maybe you find what you need. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739931/two-divs-to-get-fixed-position-one-after-the-other-at-the-top/34742935#34742935)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you provide 3 codes in total. One on the question, another on comment and finally another one on production website.
With that and previous comments I think that I know what do you want to do.

In this answer I drop your dependency on `Viewport selections for jQuery` plugin and use *pure* jQuery instead. I drop that dependency because that don't work as you expected and just add complexity to the needed logic.

What we need is an event handler for scroll that set a node to fadeOut when **scrolling down** after a specific point and fadeIn when **scrolling up** after reachs a specific point too.

You almost get it right the part of *specific point* with the code provided in comments but you forgot (or didn't realize) the core part: **detect when is scrolling down and when is scrolling up!**

So, here's the code:

```
var scrollTopStartFadeOut = 300; // In wich scroll position we are going to start fade Out
var scrollTopStartFadeIn = 720; // In wich scroll position we are going to start fade Out

var lastScrollTop = 0; //We set a variable to store the last scroll top
$(window).scroll( function(){
    var actualScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); 
    if (actualScrollTop >= lastScrollTop && actualScrollTop > scrollTopStartFadeOut){ // Is scrolldown and scrolltop is after the scrolltop for fadeout? Then, we fade out!
        $('#header').removeClass('fadeInUp').addClass('animated fadeOut');
        console.log('fadeOut');
    } 
    else if (actualScrollTop < lastScrollTop && actualScrollTop < scrollTopStartFadeIn){ // Is scrollup and scrolltop is before the scrolltop for fadein? Then, we fade in!
        $('#header').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        console.log('fadeInUp');
    }
    lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); // Updates the lastScrollTop
});
```

To detect (well, rudimentary detect) when is scrolling down and when is scrolling up we set a variable called `lastScrollTop` in wich we are going to store the last `scrollTop` value. With that value we can **compare** it with the actual `scrolltop` and then know when is going up (if last is bigger than actual) and when is going down (if last is lower than actual).

Also, I set two variables to change the `scrollTop` value to made the **fadeOut** or **fadeIn**. I think that the values on the answer match with the desired effect on the production website.

At last there's another detail to make this working, whe need to remove the class of the oposite effect **before** adding the new one.

I hope that you can understand everything but if there's something not well explained or something, please, let us know!

I made a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqgtk9ya/3/)** to show the effect:

Comment: can u try with 2 element ?

Comment: try with to 3 div but it's all fadeout when i scroll down

Comment: @achrafbans I think I don't know what are you referring to, could you explain what problem are you facing with the solution provided? What isn't working as expected?